# Converting Matrix4x4 to position ，Scale， Euler three vector3

Tags: math, matrix, glm-math

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    glm::mat4 t(1);
    glm::mat4 r(1);
    glm::mat4 s(1);

    t = glm::translate(t, glm::vec3(10.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f));
    r = glm::rotate(r, glm::radians(90.0f), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    s = glm::scale(s, glm::vec3(-3.0f, -5.0f, -10.0f));

    glm::mat4 trs = t * r * s;

    glm::vec3 restorePos;
    glm::vec3 restoreRot;
    glm::vec3 restoreSca;
    getPRS(trs, restorePos, restoreRot, restoreSca); 
}
```

Converting Matrix4x4 to position，Scale，Euler three vector3

```
void getPRS(const glm::mat4 &trs, glm::vec3 &pos, glm::vec3& rot, glm::vec3& sca) { 
    pos.x = transformation[3][0];
    pos.y = transformation[3][1];
    pos.z = transformation[3][2];
}
```

how to express rot and sca to make the function right?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your question is so compressed that it is difficult to understand what you mean. Please edit your question to use complete sentences and add more context and detail.

Comment: [Given this transformation matrix, how do I decompose it into translation, rotation and scale matrices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237369/given-this-transformation-matrix-how-do-i-decompose-it-into-translation-rotati?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)